# Equation of shortest distance between two lines

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry, 3d

There are two equations of line given: 
$x - y + z = 0 = 2x - 3y + 4z$  
$x + y + 2z - 3 = 0 = 2x + 3y + 3z - 4$.

We need to find the length and equation of shortest distance between these lines. I got the length as $13/\sqrt{66}$ using projection method, but I am not getting the second part of finding the equation.

The answer is given as $3x - y - z = 0 = x + 2y + z - 1$. Please help with the steps/hints involved to reach here.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: "Using projection method": what is this method ?

Comment: Find two points $A_1$ and $B_1$ on the first line, two points $A_2$ and $B_2$ in the second line. Parametrize them as $X_u=A_1+u(B_1-A_1)$ and $Y_v=A_2+v(B_2-A_2)$. Express that the distance $\|X_uY_v\|^2$ is minimal by expressing that the partial derivatives with respect to $u$ and to $v$ are $0$ at the minimal distance.

Comment: Shortest distance is perpendicular to both lines. That's why it is perpendicular to $n_1\times n_2$ and $n_3\times n_4$, where $n_1(1,-1,1)$, $n_2(2,-3,4)$, $n_3(1,1,2)$, $n_4(2,3,3)$ (coefficients for line equations). $n_1\times n_2=n_5(-1,-2,-1)$, $n_3\times n_4=n_6(-3,1,1)$. Then equation of line containing shortest distance must look like $-x-2y-z+d_5=0=-3x+y+z+d_6$. Then one needs to find such $d_5$ and $d_6$ that this line intersects both given lines.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thank You!...What I meant by Projection method was...first I found the direction cosines of the shortest distance, then I found the magnitude of the shortest distance by using the projection on a line concept...( x1 - x2)L + (y1 - y2)M + (z1 - z2)N

Answer (score 1):

The two line given are respectively $l_1$ and $l_2$; $P_1=0, Q_1=(1,2,1)\in l_1; P_2=(5,-2,0), Q_2=(2,-1,1) \in l_2$
$$\vec{P_1Q_1}=(1,2,1), \vec{P_2Q_2}=(-3,1,1), \vec{n}:=\vec{P_1Q_1}\times \vec{P_2Q_2}=(1,-4,7)$$
$l_1=\mathbb R (1,2,1), l_2=(5,-2,0)+\mathbb R(-3,1,1)$

We are looking for an equation of the plane containing $l_1$ and directed by $\vec{n}$. A vector orthogonal to this plane is $\vec{n}\times\vec{P_1Q_1}=-6(3,-1,-1)$. So $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$ is in this plane iff $3x-y-z=0$.

We are looking for an equation of the plane containing $l_2$ and directed by $\vec{n}$. A vector orthogonal to this plane is $\vec{n}\times\vec{P_2Q_2}=-11(1,2,1)$. So $M=(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$ is in this plane $\iff \langle\vec{Q_2M},(1,2,1)\rangle=0 \iff x+2y+z-1=0$

Hence the answer given.
[image]